# Change barTintColor in activityViewController

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, bartintcolor

I have a swift 4 / iOS 12 application that uses a custom navbar barTintColor for all view controllers and is set in appDelegate.swift like so:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 229/255, green: 80/255, blue: 57/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

However, id'l like to change the color when I present an activityViewController so that the mail compose view get a white barTint. I've achieved this by doing:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textShare , applicationActivities: nil)
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: { () in

                UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
            })
```

But when I dismiss the activityViewController the tintColor of the navbar has changed for the whole application. This is not the behavior that I want. I want the tintColor to be set back when I dismiss activityViewController, but I can't figure out how to catch the "willDisappear" function so I can set it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIActivityViewController` is subclass of `UIViewController` so you can override its method like `viewWillDisappear`, `viewDidAppear`, etc.

So first create your custom subclass of `UIActivityViewController` and then override its `viewWillDisappear` method and declare what should happen when ViewController will disappear.

```
class YourActivityViewController: UIActivityViewController {
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 229/255, green: 80/255, blue: 57/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

then just declare your `activityViewController` as your `UIActivityViewController` subclass

```
let activityViewController = YourActivityViewController(activityItems: textShare , applicationActivities: nil)
```

Comment: it does change the barTintColor but not before I go to another tab. The navbar remains white when UIActivityViewController disappears.